# Reading data from keyboard

Tags: python-3.x

I am given an assignment where I have to read input from keyboard and extract the data.For example

```
 Djokovic:Murray:2-6,6-7,7-6,6-3,6-1
 Murray:Djokovic:6-3,4-6,6-4,6-3
```

This will be data and I have to extract different like number of sets won etc..I am done with coding part of extracting data(like calculating total no.of games played etc.). But I am confused how to read data continuosly from keyboard.If I use `input()`  I am expecting that `input()` reads only one line(it reads only Djakovic:Murray but it does not read Murray:Djakovic).Further it is given that each line is terminated by a blank  line.How can I read data continuosly from keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap your code into `while True:` and break it when you get a blank line...